Does Portkeys always work backwards as well?
The Triwizard cup was made a portkey by Barty Crouch Jr to transport Harry to the graveyard at Little Hangleton. He didn't wanted Harry to return back as Lupin told Harry at the Order of Phoenix headquarters.

'Or rather, you messed it up for him,' said Lupin, with a satisfied smile.
'How?' Harry asked, perplexed.
'You weren't supposed to survive!' said Sirius. 'Nobody apart from his
Death Eaters was supposed to know he'd come back. But you survived to bear witness.'
'And the very last person he wanted alerted to his return the moment
he got back was Dumbledore,' said Lupin. 'And you made sure Dumbledore
knew at once.'

So looks like Barty Crouch Jr didn't make the portkey double sided. So is it safe to assume that all portkeys work backward or there is something more to it?

This question is similar to: Why was the Triwizard cup portkey in Goblet of Fire two-way?. Specifically the bit “Are all the portkeys 2-way?”
